# Show that $|\mathbb{Z}^*_n|$ is even if $n\geq3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $|\mathbb{Z}^*_n|$ is even if $n \geq 3$.

I split the proof in two cases, for $n$ prime and for $n$ not prime. 
I managed the first case. I don't know how to work out the case $n$ not prime.

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close this. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an elementary proof.

If $1 \le x < n$ and $\gcd(x,n)=1$, then $\gcd(n-x,n)=1$.

So, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$ come in pairs and so there is an even number of them.

(Note that $x\ne n-x$ if $\gcd(x,n)=1$ and $n\ge3$.)

Answer (score 1):

The order of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. And what can be said about the parity of $\phi(n)$ for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: I used $\phi(n)$ for the case when $n$ is prime. Then $\phi(n)= n-1$, and $n-1$ is even.  I think I got it: $\phi(n)$ is even for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: That's right, and it can be proved using the mutiplicativity of $\phi$. If $n\geq 3$, then either $n$ is divisible by an odd prime, or $n=2^k$ with $k\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works; now use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is at least $3$, then $-1$ is not conguent to $1$, so its class in $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is an element of order $2$. Lagrange's theorem tells us that the order of the group`is then even.

Comment: +1. My answer is exactly the proof of Lagrange's theorem for the subgroup $\{1,-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use strong induction with the properties of Euler's totient function:
$\phi(p^k) = p^k - p^{k - 1}$ and $\phi(p_1^{k_1}..p_n^{k_n}) = \phi(p_1^{k_1})..\phi(p_n^{k_n})$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes.